# Django admin file upload with current model id

Tags: python, django, django-models, upload, django-admin

I'm trying to create a simple photo gallery with the default Django admin. I'd like to save a sample photo for each gallery, but I don't want to keep the filname. Instead of the filename, I'd like to save the id of the model (`N.jpg`). But the first time I want to save the object the id does not exist. How could I know the next auto increment in the model, or somehow save the model data before the upload with `super.save` and after upload the file when `self.id` is exists? Is there a cool solution?

Something like this:

```
def upload_path_handler(instance, filename):
    ext = filename extension
    return "site_media/images/gallery/{id}.{ext}".format(id=instance.nextincrement, ext=ext)

class Gallery(models.Model):
    name  = models.TextField()
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path_handler)
```

And maybe store the filename in a different field.

Comment: Why would this deserve a downvote? It is certainly a question of better quality than some.

Comment: There's no reliable way to know the id of the next record ahead of time. You could get the id after the record is initially created, but this too is subject to race conditions. My advice - pick something else besides the id to name your files with.

Comment: For example, current timestamp + microseconds

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The image file gets saved before Gallery instance. So you have to split the saving to two phases by using signals w/ Gallery instance itself carrying the state:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

_UNSAVED_FILEFIELD = 'unsaved_filefield'

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Image)
def skip_saving_file(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.pk and not hasattr(instance, _UNSAVED_FILEFIELD):
        setattr(instance, _UNSAVED_FILEFIELD, instance.image)
        instance.image = None

@receiver(post_save, sender=Image)
def save_file(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and hasattr(instance, _UNSAVED_FILEFIELD):
        instance.image = getattr(instance, _UNSAVED_FILEFIELD)
        instance.save()        
        # delete it if you feel uncomfortable...
        # instance.__dict__.pop(_UNSAVED_FILEFIELD)
```

The upload_path_handler looks like

```
def upload_path_handler(instance, filename):
    import os.path
    fn, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return "site_media/images/gallery/{id}{ext}".format(id=instance.pk, ext=ext)
```

I suggest using ImageField instead of FileField for type-checking if the field is for image uploading only. Also, you may want to normalize filename extension (which is unnecessary because of the mimetype) like

```
def normalize_ext(image_field):
    try:
        from PIL import Image
    except ImportError:
        import Image
    ext = Image.open(image_field).format
    if hasattr(image_field, 'seek') and callable(image_field.seek):
       image_field.seek(0)
    ext = ext.lower()
    if ext == 'jpeg':
        ext = 'jpg'
    return '.' + ext
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) My only comment is: sender=Image is the object of the model object if somebody else will try to use this solution.

Answer (score 45):

I ran into the same problem. Okm's answer sent me on the right path but it seems to me it is possible to get the same functionality by just overriding the `save()` method of your Model.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        saved_image = self.image
        self.image = None
        super(Material, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.image = saved_image

    super(Material, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This definitely saves the information correctly.

Comment: is this broken in django 1.7 ?

Comment: Nice solution! After a while I noticed that it breaks on unit tests, as kwargs contain 'force_insert=True' and the second save results in IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry"). Adding kwargs.pop('force_insert') at the end of the if block solves the problem.

Comment: @Louis you could pass in only the field names you wish to update in the second call to `save` by specifying `update_fields=['image']` as a parameter.

Comment: Perfect and Pythonic solution! Works in Django 2.1.5. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For Django 2.2, follow the below code.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        saved_image = self.image
        self.image = None
        super(Gallery, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.image = saved_image
        if 'force_insert' in kwargs:
            kwargs.pop('force_insert')

    super(Gallery, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Add the above code snippet to your 'class Gallery'.

> P.S.: This will work for DRF as well when you save via views.py.
>   Note that second if (condition) is required for DRF.

Comment: You can save one line with `kwargs.pop('force_insert', None)`. 
Also, Django 2.2 is for Python 3, so you can write `super().save(*args, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Louis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15776267/7311767), here is recipe to process all `FileField` in the model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    file_field = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.id is None:
            saved = []
            for f in self.__class__._meta.get_fields():
                if isinstance(f, models.FileField):
                    saved.append((f.name, getattr(self, f.name)))
                    setattr(self, f.name, None)

            super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

            for name, val in saved:
                setattr(self, name, val)
        super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

In django 1.7, the proposed solutions didn't seem to work for me, so I wrote my FileField subclasses along with a storage subclass which removes the old files.

Storage:

```
class OverwriteFileSystemStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def _save(self, name, content):
        self.delete(name)
        return super()._save(name, content)

    def get_available_name(self, name):
        return name

    def delete(self, name):
        super().delete(name)

        last_dir = os.path.dirname(self.path(name))

        while True:
            try:
                os.rmdir(last_dir)
            except OSError as e:
                if e.errno in {errno.ENOTEMPTY, errno.ENOENT}:
                    break

                raise e

            last_dir = os.path.dirname(last_dir)
```

FileField:

```
def tweak_field_save(cls, field):
    field_defined_in_this_class = field.name in cls.__dict__ and field.name not in cls.__bases__[0].__dict__

    if field_defined_in_this_class:
        orig_save = cls.save

        if orig_save and callable(orig_save):
            assert isinstance(field.storage, OverwriteFileSystemStorage), "Using other storage than '{0}' may cause unexpected behavior.".format(OverwriteFileSystemStorage.__name__)

            def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if self.pk is None:
                    orig_save(self, *args, **kwargs)

                    field_file = getattr(self, field.name)

                    if field_file:
                        old_path = field_file.path
                        new_filename = field.generate_filename(self, os.path.basename(old_path))
                        new_path = field.storage.path(new_filename)
                        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(new_path), exist_ok=True)
                        os.rename(old_path, new_path)
                        setattr(self, field.name, new_filename)

                    # for next save
                    if len(args) > 0:
                        args = tuple(v if k >= 2 else False for k, v in enumerate(args))

                    kwargs['force_insert'] = False
                    kwargs['force_update'] = False

                orig_save(self, *args, **kwargs)

            cls.save = save


def tweak_field_class(orig_cls):
    orig_init = orig_cls.__init__

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'storage' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['storage'] = OverwriteFileSystemStorage()

        if orig_init and callable(orig_init):
            orig_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

    orig_cls.__init__ = __init__

    orig_contribute_to_class = orig_cls.contribute_to_class

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        if orig_contribute_to_class and callable(orig_contribute_to_class):
            orig_contribute_to_class(self, cls, name)

        tweak_field_save(cls, self)

    orig_cls.contribute_to_class = contribute_to_class

    return orig_cls


def tweak_file_class(orig_cls):
    """
    Overriding FieldFile.save method to remove the old associated file.
    I'm doing the same thing in OverwriteFileSystemStorage, but it works just when the names match.
    I probably want to preserve both methods if anyone calls Storage.save.
    """

    orig_save = orig_cls.save

    def new_save(self, name, content, save=True):
        self.delete(save=False)

        if orig_save and callable(orig_save):
            orig_save(self, name, content, save=save)

    new_save.__name__ = 'save'
    orig_cls.save = new_save

    return orig_cls


@tweak_file_class
class OverwriteFieldFile(models.FileField.attr_class):
    pass


@tweak_file_class
class OverwriteImageFieldFile(models.ImageField.attr_class):
    pass


@tweak_field_class
class RenamedFileField(models.FileField):
    attr_class = OverwriteFieldFile


@tweak_field_class
class RenamedImageField(models.ImageField):
    attr_class = OverwriteImageFieldFile
```

and my upload_to callables look like this:

```
def user_image_path(instance, filename):
    name, ext = 'image', os.path.splitext(filename)[1]

    if instance.pk is not None:
        return os.path.join('users', os.path.join(str(instance.pk), name + ext))

    return os.path.join('users', '{0}_{1}{2}'.format(uuid1(), name, ext))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a model instance by passing cleaned data from your form as **kwargs to django model i did it that way & its much easier than anything else

in your views post method add this (this code is from my project not adapted to this question)

```
    pk = request.session['_auth_user_id']
    user_obj = User.objects.get(pk=pk)


    lab_form_instance = lab_form(request.POST,request.FILES)
    lab_form_instance.save(commit=False)
    # here you can put the form.is_valid() statement
    lab_form_instance.cleaned_data['owner'] =user_obj # here iam adding additional needed data for the model
    obj = lab(**lab_form_instance.cleaned_data)
    obj.save()
```

*django==4.1