# How save filename of uploaded file in model

Tags: django, django-admin

I need save without full path to file also filename.
I doing so:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = settings.PATH_PHOTOS_SOURCE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, editable=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, default=0)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.filename = os.path.basename(self.photo.url)
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It's work, but exist cases, when file with existing name already exist, and offcourse in disk write file example_1.jpg, example_2.jpg, but in filename saving incorrect filename example.jpg

I changed my save method so:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)        
    self.filename = os.path.basename(self.photo.url)
    super(Photo, self).save()
```

It's work, but i don't like this code, maybe is more elegant code.

I tried to do this with signals, but i had problem with save recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `settings.PATH_PHOTOS_SOURCE`, [pass a function to upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

```
def upload_path_handler(self, filename):
    return os.path.join(settings.PATH_PHOTOS_SOURCE,
                        os.path.basename(self.photo.url))

# in model
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path_handler)
```

If you want to use model instance id for filename, ref [Django admin file upload with current model id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968532/django-admin-file-upload-with-current-model-id)

You may need to consider possible value of photo.url to make sure its safe to directly use it as filename.