# How to change the filename on uploaded file?

Tags: django

I have a `ImageField()` where I have specified the `upload_to` path. And it works it saves to the `MEDIA_ROOT` url. However I want to change the uploaded file to some other filename.

Should I do that from the forms.py or from the models.py, and also should I override the the save function to archive that?

**forms.py**

```
class UserAvatarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('avatar',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserAvatarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customize it in [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) of the `ImageField` avatar directly.

Normally it looks like

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    import os.path
    # get extension from raw filename
    fn, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    new_filename = ...
    # return new filename, including its parent directories (based on MEDIA_ROOT)
    return "path/{new_filename}{ext}".format(new_filename=new_filename, ext=ext)
```

You could introduce new name at the `new_filename` line, depends on `instance` or `filename` or any other strings that makes sense. It's even possible to [name the file by instance.pk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968532/django-admin-file-upload-with-current-model-id)

Comment: I save that it had `filename` argument. But I couldn't understand how to use it. Could you perhaps give a small example how to use it?

Comment: @starcorn please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088693/how-save-filename-of-uploaded-file-in-model/10089200#10089200 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968532/django-admin-file-upload-with-current-model-id

Comment: thanks, I tried some myself also. And got some working solution. But your's was better ;)