# Modifying file name of a file in a Django ModelForm on save

Tags: python, django, forms, file, modelform

I have a ModelForm with a FileField, among other fields. I wanted to modify the filename on calling myform.save() to avoid collisions (insert 6 random characters to the filename). What's the proper way to do this in Django?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433440/how-to-change-the-filename-on-uploaded-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override your Model's **`save`** method, not your Form's.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # other fields
    my_file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploaddir')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_name = 'file_name-random-chars.ext'
        self.my_file.name = new_name
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Your ModelForm for `MyModel` will call it's model's save method and do the trick.
Hope it helps :)