# saving an image as [self.id].jpg on DJANGO admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I need an admin on django to be able to upload an image that should be saved as /path/{self.id}.jpg

So far I have a database with id,status,title fields and a model with id,status,title,THUMB fields:

```
class MEL(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=( (0, 'inactive'), (1, 'active') ), default=1)
    title = models.TextField(verbose_name='Título')
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'MEL'
```

The problem is that the image is uploaded previously to the model being saved, so I can't save it to "self.id" at this moment.
I think I could save it to /tmp/{uuid} and then renaming it post-save, probably something like:

```
def upload_path(self, filename):
    self.file_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
    return '/tmp/' + self.file_uuid
```

and then a post-save that renames it and delete it from /tmp/

Or I could try overriding this model's save() method to first call super().save(), then process the image upload (which is in a ImageFieldFile object) and rename it to self.id

suggestions?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django admin file upload with current model id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968532/django-admin-file-upload-with-current-model-id)

Comment: This is the best [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15776267/1761793) to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to change the filename using upload_to.  I say this because I have done it in projects and the django documentation says so:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

The third paragraph down of that link says this: "This may also be a callable, such as a function, which will be called to obtain the upload path, **including the filename**." [emphasis added].  I'm not trying to be sarcastic I'm just showing that this is and should be possible so something else must be going on.

try something like this.  The problem could be that you were leaving off the extension:

```
def upload_path(self, filename):
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return '/'.join(["path",("%s%s" % (self.id, extension))])
```

Comment: `self.id` is `None`  as the model is not yet saved