# Django ImageField upload_to value from M2M relation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to set up `upload_to` value of ImageField from slug of ManyToMany field.

Here's my model:

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('gallery', str(instance.albums.all()[0]), filename)

class Image(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
    ...
```

Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. When I try to save Image object I get an error:

> 'Image' instance needs to have a primary key value before a
>   many-to-many relationship can be used.

Is there any correct way of doing it?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must save  the `instance`, which is an instance of `Image()`, and M2M relations w/ `albums`, at first, before access `instance.albums.all()`.

Check [Django admin file upload with current model id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968532/django-admin-file-upload-with-current-model-id) for the point of saving `Model` before using it's `pk` in `upload_to()`. Since M2M get in the way here, instead of `post_save()` method mentioned in the post, use `m2m_changed` signal to inform the ready of `instance.albums.all()`, something like:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Image.albums.through)
def save_file_on_m2m(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add' and hasattr(instance, _UNSAVED_FILEFIELD):
        instance.image = getattr(instance, _UNSAVED_FILEFIELD)
        instance.save()        
        instance.__dict__.pop(_UNSAVED_FILEFIELD)
```

This depends on the m2m values for `Image.albums`, if there is not any, `image` would be lost. Thus I would suggest using some other key which is more solid then this.

Also you may work on modelform directly to save `image` field manually, after save the `Image()` itself and M2M relations.