# FileField with instance id in DRF

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I don't know why filefield return string that include None when post data.

**like this**

> http://example.com/room/None/1.jpg

My instance id was null on save.

In **`models.py`**

```
def room_photo_path(instance, filename):
    return 'room/{}/{}'.format(instance.id, filename)


class Room(models.Model):
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to=room_photo_path)
```

In **`serializers.py`**

```
class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id gets assigned in database so the instance needs to be saved to have an id.

`upload_to` function gets called before the object is saved to database so you can't access the id because there is no id yet.

You can use signals and use a `post_save` signal to make the changes if you really have to use ids.

[Django docs: Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/)

Comment: Hi, I understood your answer. 

So, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15776267).. but It's not working for me..
 Can I use override `save` for solve this problem? There are different between `save` function  and `post_save` signal?

Comment: You can't use `save` either. id gets assigned after save method. Basically you won't have an id unless the database gets the data and save them which means there is nothing you can do in django level. `post_save` signals sends a signal to a function after save so you can make changes while you have the id too.