# How to display a list of uploaded files with dynamic path in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to upload files to my website in dynamic path, and list all of them, but I do not know how to call the files because they are in dynamic path. The problem is I allow the filefield to be blank, so when I use 'objects.all()' it will also list the blank value which I do not want it to be shown.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

# Create your models here.

def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'uploads/{id}/{fn}'.format(id=instance.pk,fn=filename)

class Chemkin(models.Model):

    mechanism_file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    thermo_file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    transport_file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    surface_file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamps = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'upload_to'


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ 
        The folder used to upload the files to, depends on the id (primary key)
        of the Chemkin object. If that is newly created and not yet saved, it 
        doesn't have an id yet. So to save the Chemkin object and all its files,
        you need to save the Chemkin object first with no files if it has no id,
        before then saving it again with the files re-attached.
        This solution is based on john.don83 answer here
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968532/django-admin-file-upload-with-current-model-id
        """
        if self.id is None:
            files_saved_for_later = []
            for f in self.__class__._meta.get_fields():
                if isinstance(f, models.FileField):
                    files_saved_for_later.append((f.name, getattr(self, f.name)))
                    setattr(self, f.name, None)
            # Save the model once witout files to create an id
            super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            for name, val in files_saved_for_later:
                setattr(self, name, val)
        # Save the model, with all the files
        super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import Chemkinupload
from .models import Chemkin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage


# Create your views here.

class Home(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    #pass


def upload(request):
    # if request.method == 'POST':
    #     uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
    #     if uploaded_file.endwith('.inp', '.dat', '.txt', 'xls', 'xml'):
    #         fs = FileSystemStorage()
    #         file_name = fs.save(upload_file.name, uploaded_file)
    #         context['url'] = fs.url(file_name)
    #     else:

    # return render(request, 'upload.html', {})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Chemkinupload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/list/')
    else:
        form = Chemkinupload()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {
        'form': form
    })


def upload_list(request):
    uploaded_files = Chemkin.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'list.html', {
        'uploaded_files': uploaded_files
    })


def ace(request):
    return render(request, 'ace.html', {})
```

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>File name</th>
    </tr>


    <tbody>
        {% for file in uploaded_files %}
          <tr>
            <td> <a href="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ file.mechanism_file }}">{{ file.uploaded_file.name }}</a> <button>edit</button></td>
            <td><button>Download</button></td>

          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>   
</table>


{% endblock %}
```

please help me on how to retrieve the name/path of uploaded files on the list?

Comment: Not related, but `super(self.__class__, self)` is always wrong. Never do that.

Comment: But I don't understand why the fact that the path is "dynamic" is at all relevant. The path is stored in the field. What, **exactly**, is your problem?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I want to retrieve my uploaded file in a list view, but I have some blank values listed because I set `blank=True` in FileField. My question is how can I list all my uploaded files without blank values.